# Find the equation of a circle though $(2,5)$ tangent to the lines $2x-y+6=0$ and $x-2y=0$

Tags: geometry

I tried to assimilate the distance of the center of the circle to the lines and to the given point, and maybe knowing the center is on the bissector line crossing the given lines would make it easier, but it still looks it is too many calculations. Is there a better way to solve this, maybe a geometric particularity?

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

If the center is $P(h,k)$

its distance from each of the two lines will be $=$ the length of the radius $=r$(say)

Now $r^2=(h-2)^2+(k-5)^2$

Comment: @cansomeonehelpmeout, The circle passes through $(2,5)$ right?

Comment: @cansomeonehelpmeout, Exactly. That's why $$r^2=(h-2)^2+(k-5)^2$$  $r=0$ in your case

Comment: @cansomeonehelpmeout Nothing here is implying that the circle passes through the $(2,5)$.  All that's being said here is the distance from the origin $(h,k)$ to the point $(2,5)$ is the same as the distance from $(h,k)$ to each of the tangent lines.

Comment: I guess I undersand the idea, but how can we proceed? We now have a circunference centered in $(2,5)$ with an unkown radius $r$ passing through the center of the original circunference

Answer (score 1):

The center of the circle lies on the bisector of the two lines.  The slopes of the two lines are $2$ and $1/2$ so the bisector has slope $1$.  The lines intersect at $(-4,-2)$, so the equation of the bisector is $y=x+2.$  (I choose this one because it bisects the region containing the point $(2,5).)$

So the center of the circle is of the form $(x,x+2)$.  The distance from this center to the point $(2,5)$ gives us the equation

$$(x-2)^2+(x+2-5)^2 = r^2$$

or $$2x^2-10x+13 = r^2.$$

A normal vector to the second line is given by $\langle -1,2\rangle.$  If we (scalar) project the vector $\langle x, x+2\rangle$ onto the normal vector, it will give another expression for $x$ in terms of $r$.

$$\pm r= \langle x,x+2 \rangle \cdot \frac{\langle -1,2\rangle }{\sqrt{5}} =\frac{x+4}{\sqrt{5}}.$$

Or

$$r^2 = \frac{x^2+8x+16}{5}$$

Equating our two expressions for $r^2$ give us

$$9x^2-58x+49 = 0$$

which has solutions $x=1$ and $x=49/9$.  The corresponding $y$'s are $y=3$ and $y=67/9.$  The corresponding $r$'s are $ r=\sqrt{5}$  and $r=17\sqrt{5}/9.$

Comment: The two lines intersect at $(-4,-2)$, however that point is not lying on $y=x+3$. Are you sure you don't mean $y=x+2$?

Comment: @cansomeonehelpmeout  You're right.  I'll fix it after I do a couple of other chores.

Comment: It would be nice if you explained how you chose that bisector of the two.

Answer (score 0):

Let $M(xM,yM)$ be the middle Point of our circle then we get

$$(2-xM)^2+(5-yM)^2=r^2$$ and

$$\left|\frac{2xM-yM-6}{\sqrt{5}}\right|=r$$
and

$$\left|\frac{x-2y}{\sqrt{5}}\right|=r$$
you will get three equations in the unknowns $$xM,yM,r$$
Can you solve These equations?

Comment: Without a doubt. I dont't like arriving in absolute values, but I guess it is part of the game.

Comment: It is the distance between a line and the point $$M(xM,yM)$$, the so-called Hessian Normalform.